# Spring: Map Page to PageResponseModel

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I've my `PageableResponseModel` class:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class PageableResponseModel<T> {
    private static final Integer DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE      = 10;


    private Long totalResults;
    private Integer page;
    private Integer size;
    private List<T> results;
    
    public Integer getSize() {
        return
            Objects.nonNull(size)
                ? size
                : DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
    }

    public void setSize(Integer size) {
        this.size =
            Objects.nonNull(size)
                ? size
                : DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
    }
    
}
```

From my repositories, I'm getting `org.springframework.data.domain.Page<T>`:

```
Uni<Page<T>> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

I need to convert from `org.springframework.data.domain.Page<T>` to my `PageableResponseModel<T>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would add private constructor, setting the fields by invoking the API provided by [Page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) and its' superinterface [Slice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html). And public static `fromPage` method to handle corner cases, nulls, etc.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class PageableResponseModel<T> {

  private static final Integer DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 10;

  private Long totalResults;
  private Integer page;
  private Integer size;
  private List<T> results;

  //getters and setters omitted

  private PageableResponseModel(Page<T> page) {
    this.totalResults = page.getTotalElements();
    this.page = page.getNumber();
    this.size = page.getSize();
    this.results = page.getContent();
  }

  public static <R> PageableResponseModel<R> fromPage(Page<R> page) {
    if (page == null) {
      //some handling for your use case
      return new PageableResponseModel<>(Page.empty());
    }
    return new PageableResponseModel<>(page);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for `PageableResponseModel`

```
public PageableResponseModel(List<T> results, Integer page, Integer size, Long totalResults) {

    this.content = content;
    this.page = page;
    this.size = size;
    this.totalElements = totalElements;
}
```

Now in your service layer, first you need to check if the retrieved `Page<T>` has any elements or not. If it is empty, you can return a new object of

```
return new PageableResponseModel<>(Collections.emptyList(), page.getNumber(), 
       page.getSize(), page.getTotalElements());
```

Else, you get the list from the `Page<T>` using `stream` and `map` and feed the constructor like this

```
return new PageableResponseModel<>(list, page.getNumber(), page.getSize(), page.getTotalElements());
```